# PyQt button click area (Non rectangular area)

Tags: button, pyqt, pyside, maya

I was working on a PySide interface for Maya and i was wondering if its possible to define a NON RECTANGULAR clickeable area for a button.

I tried using QPushButton and also extending a QLabel object to get button behavior but do you know if its possible to get **a button containing a picture with alpha channel and use that alpha to define the click area for a button**?

I'd appreciate a lot if you can guide me through how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

I've tried this...

```
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui 

class QLabelButton(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init(self, parent):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'))

class CustomButton(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(300, 350)
        self.setMaximumSize(300, 350)

        picture = __file__.replace('qbtn.py', '') + 'mario.png'
        self.button = QLabelButton(self)
        self.button.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(picture))
        self.button.setScaledContents(True)

        self.connect(self.button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.onClick)

    def onClick(self):
        print('Button was clicked')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = CustomButton()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

[mario.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUUTn.png)

Comment: Note:

picture = __file__.replace('qbtn.py', '') + 'mario.png'

refers to the name of the python file, to get a relative path for the png file which is located at the same folder of the .py file.

Answer (score 3):

This is the final code i get to solve my above question...

```
from PySide import QtCore 
from PySide import QtGui 


class QLabelButton(QtGui.QLabel):

    def __init(self, parent):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'))

class CustomButton(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(300, 350)
        self.setMaximumSize(300, 350)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('D:\mario.png')

        self.button = QLabelButton(self)
        self.button.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.button.setScaledContents(True)
        self.button.setMask(pixmap.mask()) # THIS DOES THE MAGIC

        self.connect(self.button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.onClick)

    def onClick(self):
        print('Button was clicked')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by catching the press/release events and checking the position of the click with the value of the pixel in the image to decide if the widget should emit a click or not.

```
class CustomButton(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent, image):
        super(CustomButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.image = image

    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.image.size()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # Position of click within the button
        pos = event.pos()
        # Assuming button is the same exact size as image
        # get the pixel value of the click point.
        pixel = self.image.alphaChannel().pixel(pos)

        if pixel:
            # Good click, pass the event along, will trigger a clicked signal
            super(CustomButton, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        else:
            # Bad click, ignore the event, no click signal
            event.ignore()
```

Comment: Hi Brendan, thanks for your reply. Finally i got the solution, just one more line of code.